# accept() doesn't block after client close (with Ctrl+C) error 10093

Tags: c++, network-programming, signals, winsock2

I'm developing a simple client-server application using `winsock2`, in which I send an integer value from the client and the server receives it.
When I send one (or more) integer and the client closes the socket correctly, the server understands that the client has closed the connection and goes to the `accept()` function waiting for another connection. 
However, **when I stop the client for example with the combination `Ctrl+C`, the `accept()` doesn't stops and continues the main loop of the server returning error `10093` every time it loops** (which is involved with `WSAStartup()`).
I think that in some way I have to manage the signal that is sent to the server, like `SIPIPE` in Linux, or something similar, but I don't know how. 
What is the best way to manage this problem? 
Here my accept implementation:

```
bool Network::Accept() {
    caddrlen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    int ret; 
    if ((ret = accept(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &caddrlen) ) == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        myFormatMessage(WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(listeningSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return false;
    }
    else {
//save client ip address in a string
        getpeername(listeningSocket, (SOCKADDR *)&clientAddr, (int *)sizeof(clientAddr));
        char ip[20];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, (sockaddr*)&clientAddr.sin_addr, ip, 20);
        clientIPaddr.assign(ip);
        connectedSocket = ret; 
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winsock error 10093 is [`WSANOTINITIALISED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668.aspx):

> Successful WSAStartup not yet performed.
>   Either the application has not called WSAStartup or WSAStartup failed. The application may be accessing a socket that the current active task does not own (that is, trying to share a socket between tasks), **or WSACleanup has been called too many times**.

Your `Network::Accept()` method is calling `WSACleanup()` when `accept()` fails for any reason.  `Network::Accept()` should not be doing that at all.  It should not also be closing the listening socket, either.  Remove those two lines from `Network::Accept()`, and then make your main loop stop calling `Network::Accept()` if it returns false, and then clean up your listening socket as needed.

There are other problems with your `Network::Accept()` code as well:

- `accept()` returns a `SOCKET`, not an `int`.
- when `accept()` succeeds, you are calling `getpeername()` with bad parameter values.  You are passing in the listening socket instead of the accepted client socket, and you are passing in an invalid pointer for its `namelen` parameter (you need to pass a pointer to your `caddrlen` value, not type-cast the return value of `sizeof()`).  For that matter, calling `getpeername()` is redundant anyway since `accept()` has already given you the same address that `getpeername()` would give you.
- when calling `inet_ntop()`, you are type-casting the client address's `sin_addr` field to a `sockaddr*`, which is wrong.  But in this case, the compiler accepts it since the `pAddr` parameter is a `void*`.  You don't need the type-cast at all.
- if `listeningSocket` is an `AF_INET` (IPv4) socket, then hard-coding `AF_INET` when calling `inet_ntop()` is fine, since the accepted client will always be using an IPv4 address (`sockaddr_in`).  However, if you want/need to support IPv6 (and you should), then you should be checking the client's actual address family to know whether the address is using a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` and then pass parameters to `inet_ntop()` accordingly.

With that said, try something more like this:

If you are supporting IPv4 only:

```
bool Network::Accept() {
    // declare clientAddr as sockaddr_in...
    caddrlen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    SOCKET ret = accept(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &caddrlen);
    if (ret == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        myFormatMessage(WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    //save client ip address in a string
    char ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(clientAddr.sin_addr), ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    clientIPaddr.assign(ip);
    // declare connectedSocket as SOCKET...
    connectedSocket = ret; 
    return true;
}
```

If you are supporting IPv6 only:

```
bool Network::Accept() {
    // declare clientAddr as sockaddr_in6...
    caddrlen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    SOCKET ret = accept(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &caddrlen);
    if (ret == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        myFormatMessage(WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    //save client ip address in a string
    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
    inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(clientAddr.sin6_addr), ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
    clientIPaddr.assign(ip);
    // declare connectedSocket as SOCKET...
    connectedSocket = ret; 
    return true;
}
```

If you are supporting both IPv4 and IPv6:

```
bool Network::Accept() {
    // declare clientAddr as SOCKADDR_STORAGE...
    caddrlen = sizeof(clientAddr);
    SOCKET ret = accept(listeningSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &caddrlen);
    if (ret == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        myFormatMessage(WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    //save client ip address in a string
    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN] = {0};
    switch (clientAddr.ss_family)
    {
        case AF_INET:
            inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(((struct sockaddr_in*)&clientAddr)->sin_addr), ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &((struct sockaddr_in6*)&clientAddr)->sin6_addr), ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
            break;
    }
    clientIPaddr.assign(ip);
    // declare connectedSocket as SOCKET...
    connectedSocket = ret; 
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all this hints!